# Unable to change the font family in GXT text Area

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, gxt

I am not able to change the default font family of GXT Text Area. I have tried using StyleInjector and CSS. But it is not getting updated. Can you please help me?

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setStyleName("gxtTextArea");
```

And in the CSS file, I have given as,

```
.gxtTextArea {
    font-family: Arial !important; 
    /* color: red !important;
    font-size: 24px !important;
    font-style: bold !important;        
    font-weight: bold !important; */
}
```

Comment: if you could provide a fiddle, im pretty sure i could help you ;)

Comment: Which version of GXT are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use addStyleName instead of setStyleName.

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.addStyleName("gxtTextArea");
```

And in the CSS side, change it as below.

```
.gxtTextArea * {
    font-family: Arial !important; 
    /* color: red !important;
    font-size: 24px !important;
    font-style: bold !important;        
    font-weight: bold !important; */
 }
```